# React - How Do You Call Methods From One Component To The Other Without Adding Extra Code In The Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a toast component in React and I'm want to create it so the user can simply import the component and then not have to add any extra code other than calling methods.

For e.g.

Import Toast from './components/Toast;

And then call methods to show different toasts depending on what they want for e.g

Toast.success();

And this will return a toast with success styling and content

Or Toast.error();

And this will return a toast with error styling and content

I don't want them to do anything other than call the method after importing.

I'm struggling to think of the way you would do this.

Here is my current code:

If you look at the 'CSToastAPI' section that's where I'm struggling how I would be able to do that and call in another component. Thanks.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import CSIcon from './CSIcon';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

export interface CSToastProps {
    className?: string;
    closeButton?: boolean;
    detail?: string;
    iconName?: string;
    iconVisibility?: boolean;
    minWidth?: string;
    onClose?: undefined;
    text?: string;
    textAlign?: string;
    position?: string;
}

export interface CSToastState {
    variant?: string;
}

const CSToastAPI = {
    success: () => {
        this.setState({
            variant: 'success'
        });
    }
}

class CSToast extends React.Component<CSToastProps, CSToastState> {
    public static defaultProps = {
        iconVisibility: true
    };

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            variant: ''
        }
    }

    render() {
        const toastClasses = classNames(
            'cs-toast-wrapper',
            'top-right',
            {
                [`${this.props.position}`]: this.props.position
            }
        );

        const CSToastHTML = (
            <>
                <div className={toastClasses}>
                    <div
                        style={{minWidth: this.props.minWidth}} className={`cs-toast ${this.state.variant ? `cs-toast-${this.state.variant}` : ''} ${this.props.textAlign ? this.props.textAlign : ''} ${this.props.className ? this.props.className : ''}`} role="alert"
                        >
                            {this.props.iconVisibility ? (this.props.iconName ? (
                                <CSIcon name={this.props.iconName}/>
                            ) : (
                                <CSIcon name={this.state.variant}/>
                            )) : null}
                            <h4 className="cs-toast-text">
                                {this.props.text}
                                {this.props.detail ? (
                                    <div className="cs-toast-detail">{this.props.detail}</div>
                                ) : null}
                                {this.props.children}
                            </h4>
                            {this.props.closeButton ? (
                                <button className="cs-toast-close" onClick={this.props.onClose} aria-label="close">
                                        <CSIcon name="close"/>
                                </button>
                            ) : null}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        );

        const CSToastAPIView = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(CSToastHTML);

        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", CSToastAPIView);

        CSToastAPI.success();

        return (
            <div>
                {CSToastHTML}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CSToast;
```

Comment: Here's a minimal example: https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-bush-0ufxn?file=/src/App.js (react agnostic implementation!)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I need to do it using state rather than using the DOM.

Comment: Right, I don't know that's even possible though. As far as I can see, a state based implementation means that Toast is a component, which means some parent further up the tree manages the state of the toast. So the child that wishes to show a toast *has* to call a function that was passed as a prop, which contradicts your requirement.

Comment: Hi Chris, yeah you might be right :)